# Am I correct with this line of reasoning? (would/would have)

Tags: grammar

1. I thought you *would* come.

Here, I was thinking that you would come in the future, this sentence shows futurity in the past.

2. I thought you *would have* come.

But here, I thought that you already came with the added meaning of "willingness" that's why I used "would have". Here I could have used "had come" but this would not have conveyed the added meaning of "willingness".

Am I right with this line of reasoning or not? Please explain if I'm wrong.

Comment: [I thought you had already come]

Comment: What's wrong with the second one? What does the 2nd sentence convey?

Answer (score 2):

Compare...

> 3: *I thought you would **eat***
> 4: *I thought you would **have eaten***

...where #3 implies *...but I see you **are not currently eating***, and #4 implies *...but I see you **did not eat earlier*** (in both cases, *I thought something, **but I was mistaken***).

It just so happens that the Unmarked Infinitive and the Past Participle of ***to come*** are the same. But just as in my example, OP's #2 refers to an action that I thought ***would have already happened in the past***. This leads to the *likely* (but not "fixed") interpretation that #2 refers to an occasion in the past when the addressee ***did not attend***, whereas the most likely interpretation of #1 is that the addressee ***did*** just arrive (if not, he wouldn't be there to be spoken to! :).

---

Note that the difference between whether the speaker's preconceptions are/were confirmed or not primarily turns on whether stress is placed on ***thought*** or ***you*** (implies you ***did*** come; my expectations were confirmed) or on the word ***come*** (implies you ***didn't***).

So what I wrote above about "likely" meanings only applies to a written text *considered in isolation* (with no context and no indication of stress patterns). *Real* language is spoken, and in practice there would be no ambiguity because native speakers would *always* indicate the intended meaning by the choice of which word to stress.

Comment: IF the addressee  did just arrive then what's the need for even saying #1 lol?

Comment: You wrote your examples, not me! Seriously, it would be perfectly natural for addressee to say *I **thought** you would come!* (or *I thought **you** would come!*, more strongly implying *I expected that you of all people would be **bound** to come*). It's a bit harder to imagine the context  where stress falls on ***come*** in your example #1. But, for example, it would work fine if speaker was at the party, but ***talking on the phone*** to his friend (who he *mistakenly* expected to see at the party).

Comment: My point is it depends on the intended meaning the speaker wants to convey. Let's take your example, in #3, lets assume A is the point in time the speaker "thinks"  that listener was going to eat, let B be the  point in time listener was supposed to "eat". So B comes after A here. And now in #4, B comes before A, that is, the speaker thought the listener must have already eaten.

Comment: I don't really understand your "A" and "B" times. Are you trying to tell me something, or seek further clarification? In both your examples, ***I thought*** refers to a time in the past when the speaker thought something (which may be confirmed OR ruled out by later developments, as indicated by vocal stress). Where #1 implies he thought addressee would come ***now***, and #2 implies he thought addressee would [have] come ***then***.

Comment: Let me poke at this from a different angle, how would you frame a sentence for when the speaker thought that the listener already ate but wanted to also add the meaning of "expectation", that is he expected him to have "already" eaten. Wouldn't #4 be the suitable sentence for that? That is when speaker was "thinking", he expected the listener to have already eaten. But #3 conveys when he was "thinking" the listener  did not start eating.

Comment: Again, I don't understand *when the speaker thought that the listener already ate but wanted to also add the meaning of "expectation"*. The "meaning of expectation" is unavoidably conveyed by ***I thought*** (that's why the speaker is saying those words in the first place). The potential for ambiguity arises from the fact that ***exactly the same sequence of words*** can be used regardless of whether speaker is saying he now realises that what he thought is in fact ***incorrect***, or pointing out that his expectations have been ***confirmed***.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129579/discussion-between-english-more-exc-than-laws-and-fumblefingers).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes seeing a context helps to understand usage.

Dialogue 1:
PRESENT TIME
John: It was great that you asked me over for dinner tonight. I really wasn't busy.
Mary: Yes, I thought it **would** be a good time to invite you.
John: Oh, you're making shrimp?
Mary: Yeah, I thought you **would eat** that up in a flash.
John: I hate to tell you but I'm super allergic to shrimp.

[refers to the present: I thought you would eat that up when I invited  you.]

Dialogue 2: PRESENT TIME

John: It was great that you asked me over for dinner **last night**. I really wasn't busy.
Mary: Yes, I thought it was good time to invite you.
John: Oh, but you made shrimp....
Mary: Yeah, I thought you **would have eaten** that **up** in a flash. I didn't know you were allergic. Oh, well, there's always a next time.

[would have eaten: refers to the night before]

Comment: I thought it might help to consider TO EAT rather than TO COME for the "thought about" action, but the OP's question specifically asks about the latter. Which arguably presents somewhat different issues when it comes to "interpretation of likely intended meaning" (with focus on the ***times*** at which things were done or thought, rather than the semantics of the actions themselves).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Any verb can be used to illustrate: would + infinitive/would have + past participle.

Comment: look at this sentence-
The Pandemic might just be the best thing that could have happened to your business!
Why did they use "could have" when pandemic actually happened in reality. I thought "could have", "would have" constructions are used for imagined actions in the past that in reality did not happen.

Comment: @English--moreexcthanlaws "that **could have happened but didn't**". Could have happened does not mean did happen. "This **could have been** the best experience of your life but, in fact, **it wasn't**."

Comment: Bruh, pandemic did happen, didn't it? So if it did happen how is that construction possible?

Comment: The pandemic might just be the best thing that **can happen** to you. **could** is the past tense of **can** and it has nothing to do with logic. **It is an opinion not a factual description**. "Bruh, **the** pandemic did happen". You are confusing facts and an opinions expressed by a speaker. One can believe that anything is good for someone....Don't confuse that with: I could go if I wanted to.

Comment: If I said "the meteor could have killed the human species", this means in reality the meteor didn't actually kill anyone  but it really could have if it had hit the earth. Now look at this " The Pandemic might just be the best thing that could have happened to your business", so this means pandemic didn't really happen and your business is still normal as pandemic could have happened but it didn't?

Comment: @English--moreexcthanlaws: In your "might just be the best thing that could have happened to your business" example, the "hypothetical" past condition isn't whether the pandemic ***happened*** or not - it's ***whether or not it was the BEST thing*** that could have happened. A question which is still "unresolved" at the later time of speaking (but with speaker strongly implying it ***was*** the best possible thing).

Comment: Interesting, would you give the same explanation to this one https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113264/could-happen-and-could-have-happened

Comment: @English--moreexcthanlaws The following sentence from that answer is wrong: "Could happen is used when something actually had happened in the past". "could happen" is **never past tense**.

Comment: "could happen" could be past tense, like "I could ride a bike when I was thirteen". which is past tense, but "could have happened" will always be hypothetical past tense

Comment: @English--moreexcthanlaws I already explained that: in your example now "could ride" is the past tense of can. could happen, repeat **could happen** is not past tense. could ride a bicycle at 13 = past tense of can. Repeat past tense of can.  Two different uses.

Comment: lol who claimed 'could "happen"' is past? It was a given that he meant "could" as the past .

Comment: @English--moreexcthanlaws The link **you provided** said: "Could happen is used when something actually had happened in the past".  I wonder what your game is. It's starting to feel like you are gaslighting. Please stop.